# How to allow multi-tenant Azure Function with EasyAuth for selected tenants only?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Given a multi-tenant configured app (azure function) with EasyAuth enabled for Azure Active Directory only, how can I limit access to only selected tenants?

The consequence of using multi-tenant app with EasyAuth was removing the Issuer URL completely which means that everyone could access the app. 
I want to limit it to a few known tenants.

**Can we somehow configure the Issuer URL to carry an array of tenant IDs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a built-in way to do this as far as I know. Assuming that is the case, you'll want to implement it yourself in your application code. For example:

- Store a list of selected tenants in your application (e.g. in a database)
- For each request, look at the `iss` (issuer) claim and compare it against your list of selected tenants
- If the `iss` claim doesn't match a selected tenant, redirect them to your custom registration page (or return 403 if you don't have one).